# In objection js i am trying to set a role and receiveng error

Tags: mysql, node.js, objection.js

here is my code
(node:10188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: insert into `user` (`email`, `name`, `password`, `role`, `username`) values ('exam@mail.ru', 'chack', 'password', 'user', 'kkkp') - ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'role' in 'field list'
(node:10188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
'use strict';
const Model = require('objection').Model;
const AppConstants = require('./../constants');



class user extends Model {

    static get tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

    static get jsonSchema() {
        return {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['username', 'password', 'email', 'name'],

            properties: {

                id: { type: 'integer' },
                username: {type: 'string',
                    unique: true ,
                    minlength: AppConstants.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
                    maxlength: AppConstants.USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH
                },

                password: {
                    type: 'string', 
                    minlength: AppConstants.PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH,
                    maxlength: AppConstants.PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH
                },
                email: { type: 'string',
                    index: { unique: true },
                },
                name: { type: 'string' 
                },
                role: { enum: ['admin', 'user'], ///////////// here is
                    default: 'user'
                }   
                }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign a type to the `role` field. Try this, please:

```
'use strict';
const Model = require('objection').Model;
const AppConstants = require('./../constants');

class user extends Model {

  static get tableName() {
    return 'user';
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['username', 'password', 'email', 'name'],

      properties: {

        id: {type: 'integer'},
        username: {
          type: 'string',
          unique: true,
          minlength: AppConstants.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
          maxlength: AppConstants.USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH
        },

        password: {
          type: 'string',
          minlength: AppConstants.PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH,
          maxlength: AppConstants.PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH
        },
        email: {
          type: 'string',
          index: {unique: true},
        },
        name: {
          type: 'string'
        },
        role: {
          type: 'string',
          enum: ['admin', 'user'], ///////////// here is
          default: 'user'
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very match i have just solve this problem 
the problem was  in table scheme